# Fortran fixed-size multidimensional arrays in interoperable derived types

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran, interop

I have a Fortran library that I am attempting to create C bindings for. The Fortran library uses fixed-size multidimensional arrays contained in derived types. (These were originally global variables in a legacy Fortran code; I am placing all of the global variables into derived types for the purpose of encapsulation.) If I create a test case in Fortran using this library, in which case the derived types are initialized in Fortran code, everything goes fine, but when I try the same in C, in which case the derived types are initialized in C as structs, I get a segmentation fault.

Here is a minimal example that shows the problem. The Fortran library also uses a grouping derived type containing other derived types, so I've included that in the example.

testmod.f90:

```
module testmod

  use iso_c_binding

  implicit none

  integer(c_int), parameter :: RSIZE1 = 360
  integer(c_int), parameter :: RSIZE2 = RSIZE1/2
  integer(c_int), parameter :: ISIZE1 = RSIZE1
  integer(c_int), parameter :: ISIZE2 = ISIZE1/4

  type, bind(c) :: struct_a
    real(c_double) :: rarray(RSIZE1,RSIZE2)
    integer(c_int) :: iarray(ISIZE1,ISIZE2)
  end type struct_a

  type, bind(c) :: struct_b
    real(c_double) :: rvec(RSIZE1)
    integer(c_int) :: ivec(ISIZE1)
  end type struct_b

  type, bind(c) :: struct_group
    type(struct_a) :: a
    type(struct_b) :: b
  end type struct_group

  contains

subroutine set_structs(group) bind(c, name="set_structs")

  type(struct_group), intent(inout) :: group
  integer i, j

  do i = 1, RSIZE1
    group%b%rvec(i) = dble(i)
    group%b%ivec(i) = i 
    do j = 1, RSIZE2
      group%a%rarray(i,j) = dble(i*j)
      group%a%iarray(i,j) = i*j
      write(*,*) "Here", i, j
    end do
  end do

end subroutine set_structs

end module testmod
```

test.h:

```
#pragma once

#define RSIZE1 360
#define RSIZE2 RSIZE1/2
#define ISIZE1 RSIZE1
#define ISIZE2 ISIZE1/4

typedef struct
{ 
  double rarray[RSIZE1*RSIZE2];
  int iarray[ISIZE1*ISIZE2];
} struct_a;

typedef struct
{ 
  double rvec[RSIZE1];
  int ivec[ISIZE1];
} struct_b;

typedef struct
{
  struct_a a;
  struct_b b;
} struct_group;

extern void set_structs(struct_group *group);
```

test.c:

```
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
  struct_group group;
  set_structs(&group);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile as follows:

```
gfortran -c -fPIC -Wall testmod.f90
gcc -c -fPIC -Wall test.c
gfortran -o test testmod.o test.o
```

When I run this, I get a segfault in set_structs for i = 1, j = 103. However, if I comment out all references to iarray, it works fine. So the issue seems to occur only when there is more than 1 multidimensional array in the Fortran derived type. A single multidimensional array works fine (struct_a with iarray commented out), and multiple 1-dimensional arrays work fine (struct_b). I have also tested without the derived types at all, just passing four arrays to Fortran from C (two 2-dimensional and 2 1-dimensional), and that works fine too. I'm kind of at my wit's end here, so I'd really appreciate some advice on how to do this properly.

EDIT: as noted by francescalus in the comment below, the problem with this example is simply that I'm trying to access out-of-bounds elements of iarray, so it's not a good example of the real problem with my code. See the accepted answer for the actual cause and solution.

Comment: Aren't you just accessing elements out of bounds?  Your `j` runs up to `RSIZE2` but the extent of the second dimension of the `iarray` component is `ISIZE2`.

Comment: Ah, stupid me. You're exactly right. Waste of a few hours on my part creating this "minimal working example." Unfortunately, that kind of error is not the problem in my actual code, so now I have to figure out what's going on there. Anyway, thanks for finding my mistake, and I will close this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem in my real code, in case anyone was wondering. It seems to be with the #defines in the header file. For example, I had statements such as the following:

```
#define IQX 360
#define IWX IQX/8+2
#define IZX IQX+IWX
```

Apparently this doesn't work, which maybe I would have known if I were more familiar with the C preprocessor. Instead, do this:

```
#define IQX 360
#define IWX 47
#define IZX 407
```

Comment: You could have [edit]ed your previous answer, which is not an actual answer in fact. This is not a discussion thread. Please see how to use this site in the [tour].